# Which tool to convert webp to gif using adobe suite

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, gif, adobe-after-effects, webp

Which adobe product can I use to convert webp files to gif? I've tried opening a webp file with both premeier and phososhop but neither recognize the file type. There are free online tools but I would like to edit files locally with existing adobe tools. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need third party plug ins. Sadly Adobe hasn't caught up to webp yet...

Githup: https://github.com/fnordware/AdobeWebM#download

Telegraphics: http://telegraphics.com.au/sw/product/WebPFormat

Either or, probably not both. I use the Telegraphics plug in.

Note that **animation** is another matter entirely. Webp must be converted to a video file first. An internet search for "webp video converter" will turn up several tools for that specifically.